# How to fix the Type error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a weird potato counter with discord.py and save it to .json file.

Code is below:

```
@client.command()
async def get(ctx):
    with open('get.json', 'r') as f:
        get = json.load(f)

    get[str(ctx.author.id)] = bal + 1

    with open('get.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(get, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send('You got 1 potato!')
```

but it gives me this error:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'`

Comment: what is `bal` in `bal + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message rather clearly states you're trying to add (`+`) a function (`bal` I would guess) and an `int`, and you can't do that.

So don't do that? Maybe call the function or something? Since you don't provide all the code, let alone in a runnable / replicable state, it's difficult to provide more help than that.